# React Hook useEffect : fetch data using axios with async await .api calling continuous the same api

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

While I fetch data from `API` and set the response to a array using `useEffect`
it call the `API` repeat continuous.

```
let [product, setproduct] = useState([]);

async function fetchData() {
    let response = await axios(
      `api`
    );
    let user = await response.data;
    setproduct(user);
    console.log(product);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html),

> **Does useEffect run after every render?** Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update. (We will later talk about how to customize this.) Instead of thinking in terms of “mounting” and “updating”, you might find it easier to think that effects happen “after render”. React guarantees the DOM has been updated by the time it runs the effects.

You can provide the empty dependency array / `[]` as second argument to `useEffect`, it is same as `componentDidMount` which will executes only once in component life cycle.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []); //This will run only once
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass empty **`[]`** as an second argument to `useEffect` method. It will be called on initial render, like below.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

// This function will be only called once
async function fetchData() {
    let response = await axios("api");
    let user = response.data;// Don't need await here
    setProduct(user);
    console.log(product);
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i think the blow example will help you through fetch API .

```
import React , {useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Courses = ()=>{

    useEffect(()=>{
        getProducts()
    })




    const getProducts = async() => {
        await axios.get('api/get_all_products')
        .then(({data}) =>{
            console.log("this is data from api ");
            console.log('data' , data);

        } )

        console.log("data ehre ");
    }


    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Products data  here</h2>

        </div>

    )
};

export default Courses;
```