# useEffect dependency array continuously calls api data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Using Axios, I'm to render backend data from a utility file in my component.

In my `useEffect` hook, I have a conditional statement to check a selected date. If the date matches, I return a time slot that is available to book an appointment.

```
const [availableDates, setAvailableDates] = useState();
const [currentTimeSlot, setCurrentTimeSlot] = useState();
const [timeSlots, setTimeSlots] = useState();
  
useEffect(() => {
    async function getData(data) {
      let tempObjStoreData = service.getTempObjStoreData();
      let dates = await service.stepDate.getAvailableData();
      console.log('dates', dates);
      setAvailableDates(dates);
      setFlagRender(true);
      // this effect will run every time currentDate is changed
      if (availableDates) {
        console.log('show dates', dates);
        // get time slots of currentDate
        let slots;
        dates.forEach((d) => {
          debugger;
          if (isEqual(availableDates, new Date(d.date))) {
            slots = d.timeSlots;
          }
        });
        setTimeSlots(slots);
      }
    }
    return getData();
  }, [availableDates]);
```

When I test the component, I can select a date. However, the time slots are only briefly shown before disappearing. Looking at `availableDates` in my console log, I see that it is continuously being called.

Looking at other S/O questions like this one: [React Hook useEffect : fetch data using axios with async await .api calling continuous the same api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766593/react-hook-useeffect-fetch-data-using-axios-with-async-await-api-calling-cont), the solution was empty brackets at the end of the `useEffect` hook:

**example from solution**

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []); //This will run only once
```

**end of my useEffect hook**

```
  }, [availableDates]);
```

However, if I remove this, I get the following error:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'availableDates'.
Either include it or remove the dependency array.
```

How can I stop useEffect from constantly rendering this data?

Comment: just call getData() instead of return getData() inside the effect.

Comment: Move availableDates to ref (useRef)

Comment: When do you want to re-trigger a new fetch? you mentioned `selected date` but I don't see it in the code...

Comment: because your use effect working Re-cursively, you needed to change `[availableDates]` to `[]` and write another one  `[availableDates]` only others action not use inside this `setAvailableDates` inside this `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `availableDates` as dependency because you only want to set it, not read from it. You probably want to add some `selectedDate` dependency as you would want to re-trigger a fetch when it changes.

I've also implemented a "dispose" function, because your async code might run after this component was removed from the DOM.

```
const [availableDates, setAvailableDates] = useState();
const [currentTimeSlot, setCurrentTimeSlot] = useState();
const [timeSlots, setTimeSlots] = useState();
  
useEffect(() => {
    let canceled = false;
    async function getData(data) {
      let tempObjStoreData = service.getTempObjStoreData();
      let dates = await service.stepDate.getAvailableData();
      if (canceled) {
         return; // ignore the result, as this `useEffect` was canceled
      }

      setAvailableDates(dates);
      setFlagRender(true);

      if (dates) {
        console.log('show dates', dates);
        // get time slots of currentDate
        let slots;
        dates.forEach((d) => {
          if (isEqual(dates, new Date(d.date))) {
            slots = d.timeSlots;
          }
        });
        setTimeSlots(slots);
      }
    }
    getData();

    return () => canceled = true;
    
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

if I'm right, since `availableDates` is updated everytime `useEffect` runs, and also `useEffect` is triggered everytime `availableDates` is changed, so an infinite loop occurs. you can eliminate the use of `availableDates` in the useEffect dependencies by replacing it with the local variable `dates`

also, returning a function with useEffect means that it'll run before the component gets unmounted. so instead of returning, simply call the async function.